# Check if linked page with typolink is hidden or not

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers, typolink

`<f:link.typolink parameter="{mylink">` links to a internal page- when this page is hidden / not visible in backend no  is set.

This breaks my html:

Instead of

```html
<div class="mylink">
  <a href="mylink">my text</a>
</div>
```

I get

```html
<div class="mylink">my text/div>
```

Is there a way to check if the linked page is visible / not hidden?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `f:uri.typolink` viewhelper to check if the resulting URI is empty or not and then generate the link with `f:typolink` as normal:

```html
<f:if condition="{f:uri.typolink(parameter: mylink)}">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{mylink}">my text</f:link.typolink>
</f:if>
```

If you do not care about attributes set in `{mylink}`, e.g. `class` or `target` you can reuse the already generated URI:

```html
<f:alias map="{uri: '{f:uri.typolink(parameter: mylink)}'}">
    <f:if condition="{uri}">
        <a href="{uri}">my text</a>
    </f:if>
</f:alias>
```